# Expectation & Variance of $\frac{1}{K+X}$ when $X \sim $ Poisson and $K=2,3,4 \ldots$

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, expected-value, variance

I recently posted a question about how to find the variance of $\frac{1}{1+X}$ where X has a Poisson distribution. [Variance of $\frac{1}{X+1}$ when $X$ has Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324156/variance-of-frac1x1-when-x-has-poisson-distribution/3324396#3324396) 
And got a very helpful answer. 
(others had already answered how to get the expectation of same [Expectation of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ of Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511722/expectation-of-frac1x1-of-poisson-distribution) ; [Expected value $\frac{1}{x+1}$ of Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521104/expected-value-frac1x1-of-poisson-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) 
I'm now realizing that I also need the expectation and variance of $\frac{1}{K+X}$ where X is Poisson, for integer values of $K>1$ too. Is there a general form of the solution for getting the expectation and variance that allows me to do this for these larger integer values of K? (In practice, I'm only going to need at most up to $K=5$ but I suspect solving for positive integer $K$ in general will be easier than solving for $K=2,3,4,5$ separately.)
I tried extending the answers for $K=1$ to $K=2$ and ran into a wall. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What wall did you run into?

Comment: Extending the reasoning for turning the 2nd moment into a hypergeometric to the case of $\frac{1}{X+K}$ where $K>1$ expectation seems more doable, though I'm still working on it. The 2nd moment I don't really know where to begin

Comment: For K=2 I've gotten for expectation: $$ \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} - \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda} - \lambda e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^2} $$ where first term is the expectation for K=1. This is suggestive of a pattern (but would probably need 1 term to generalize accurately) but the same technique I used to get answer for $K=2$ doesn't work on expectation for $K=3$  (I multiply by $(x+1)/(x+1)$ to make it into a partial version of poisson expectation minus a partial version of taylor series for $e^\lambda$. Doing this for $K=3$ gives a term that's quadratic in x, greatly complicating things)

Answer (score 2):

Let $X\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$. We compute the mean of $\frac1{K+X}$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\frac1{K+X}\right] &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{K+j} \mathbb P(X=j)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{K+j} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda } (-\lambda )^{-K} \Gamma (K,0,-\lambda ),
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(K,0,-\lambda) = \int_0^{-\lambda} t^K e^{-t}\ \mathsf dt $ is the generalized incomplete gamma function. The second moment is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac1{K+X}\right)^2\right] &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{K+j}\right)^2 e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda } \, _2F_2(K,K;K+1,K+1;\lambda )}{K^2},
\end{align}
where ${}_2F_2(K,K;K+1,K+1;\lambda)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.

The variance is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac1{K+X}\right)^2\right] - \mathbb E\left[\frac1{K+X}\right]^2 &= \frac{e^{-\lambda } \, _2F_2(K,K;K+1,K+1;\lambda )}{K^2} - (e^{-\lambda } (-\lambda )^{-K} \Gamma (K,0,-\lambda ))^2\\
&= e^{-2 \lambda } \left(\frac{e^{\lambda } \, _2F_2(K,K;K+1,K+1;\lambda )}{K^2}-(-\lambda )^{-2 K} \Gamma (K,0,-\lambda )^2\right).
\end{align}